# ¿Por qué me genera error al intentar convertir en entero?

Tags: java, jsp

[image: En la penúltima línea si el edadDos = Integer.parseInt(edad); lo ejecuto sin el if me salta error,]

*En la penúltima línea si el edadDos = Integer.parseInt(edad); lo ejecuto sin el if me salta error
Si los datos de edad nunca cambian porque detecta que es null cuando lo voy a ejecutar pero no detecta el null en el if*

Answer (score 0):

Es recomendable que siempre coloques el bloque de código antes que una captura del código. Con eso aseguras que tu respuesta no será eliminada por un moderador.

Ahora respecto a tu pregunta, en tu código, cuando pasa por el `if` estás comprobando que edad sea distinto de `null`, por lo tanto, te aseguras que esa variable tenga un valor asignado al momento de hacer el parse, de igual manera eso no asegura que el parse se pueda hacer de forma correcta, ya que el valor puede no ser convertido en un entero.

Debes controlar ese bloque de código con un try catch, ya que parseInt puede lanzar una excepción de tipo NumberFormatException.